# My PHP CURL code quit working on a CSV file after years of working

Tags: php, curl

Something changed as my page has worked for years.  The function that has the CURL code is called 4 other times to retrieve html pages and works fine.  But not long ago it quit working on one call that happens to be a CSV file.  Putting the URL in a browser causes the file to be correctly downloaded so I know the data and URL are correct.  I switched to PHP 5.6 but I think everything worked fine after that although I am not 100% positive.  It is possible I missed testing this part of the app but I doubt it.  I have Googled and looked in the archives on SO and, while I find helpful suggestions, nothing works.  This code used to work.  I added some test echo lines to the code below.  I edited the code to hide my email address and url in the useragent that was added for one of the sites I download.

```
    function read_url($url){
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'weatherapp/1.0 (www.mydomain.com, myemail@mydomain.com)');
    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo  "<!--  curl_error($ch)  -->";
    }
    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "**** read $url *********<br>";
    echo $output;
    echo "******** end of output ***********<br>";
    return $output;
}
```

The test output allows me to make sure the URL is valid and see the output.

NOTE:  In my browser, the URL below will download a file.

The URL is 
http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?product=wind&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.MET&begin_date=20161210&end_date=20161213&station=9414523&time_zone=lst_ldt&units=english&interval=h&format=csv

and the output is blank.

Again, this code worked fine for a long time.

Being open to the possibility this is a PHP5.6 issue, I searched for and found a question dealing with this that talked about adding this command

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false;
```

But that didn't help.  I tried true as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess here is that the web service has begun serving this data over HTTPS but your code does not account for that.:

```
$ curl -v 'http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?product=wind&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.MET&begin_date=20161210&end_date=20161213&station=9414523&time_zone=lst_ldt&units=english&interval=h&format=csv' 
*   Trying 140.90.78.215...
* Connected to tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov (140.90.78.215) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/datagetter?product=wind&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.MET&begin_date=20161210&end_date=20161213&station=9414523&time_zone=lst_ldt&units=english&interval=h&format=csv HTTP/1.1
> Host: tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?product=wind&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.MET&begin_date=20161210&end_date=20161213&station=9414523&time_zone=lst_ldt&units=english&interval=h&format=csv
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

So it is returning a `Location` header, but you have not configured curl to follow the redirect.  If you check `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)` you will most likely find it is returning a `302 Found` code.

Add `CURLOPT_FOLLOW_LOCATION` so your code will follow any subsequent redirects to the target resource:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

You could also change your code to request it over `https://` in the first place, but adding the redirect following will make it more robust in the long run.

Comment: I added the followlocation to true and that worked.  That is a great change as these guys drive me nuts by changing their urls every so often. I am happy to have my code now follow these links.  Thank you!